# setting the owner of the file while creating it java 1.7

Tags: file, java-7, nio

I migrated to java 1.7 to use the nio package features.

I am creating a file and using the nio package features setting the owner of the file to logged user.

```
        File file = new File(System.getProperty("<file location is in system property>")+fileName);
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        while ((read = inputstream.read(bytes)) != -1) {                                                                 //getting the input stream through vcl of the file upload
                outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
        Path path = Paths.get(System.getProperty("<file location>")+fileName);
        FacesContext faceCtx =  FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(); 
        ExternalContext extCtx = faceCtx.getExternalContext();
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest)extCtx.getRequest();

        UserPrincipalLookupService lookupService = FileSystems.getDefault().getUserPrincipalLookupService();
        FileOwnerAttributeView ownerAttributeView = Files.getFileAttributeView(path,FileOwnerAttributeView.class);
       String user=req.getHeader("<parameter to get the logged in user>")
       UserPrincipal owner = lookupService.lookupPrincipalByName(user);
       ownerAttributeView.setOwner(owner);                                                                        //throwing operation not permitted exception
```

Now, even the when i try to change the owner through chown command in the unix box i get the same error(running through the user weblogic which does not has the root permission).

Seems like only user with root permission can change the owner of a file and it is not advisable to run the weblogic domain with the root user permission.

So the question is is there a way i can set the owner at the time of creating of the file using some nio package API's???